# Server 08R2 Shutdown after updates instead of restart

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation

I'm running a server in a virtualized environment.  I would like to get it to shutdown after running updates rather than restarting so that the hyperviser can run updates and then restart.  The server will automatically launch when the hyperviser restarts.  Does anybody know how to do this or know of a better method to achieve the same thing?

Comment: How are you providing updates? Direct from Windows Update or via WSUS/SCCM?

Comment: I don't think there are any options for Windows Updates to shutdown rather than restart. Why don't you just shut down the VM after it restarts? Additionally, if this Hyper-V host is in a Failover Cluster you might look into Cluster Aware Updating.